# Excel function ( compare cell to matrix and show cell next to it )

Tags: excel, function

In excel I've got a ton of tables ( matrixes, two wide ) ( this is for a school project ).
For example:

```
1 | G
2 | O
3 | TW
```

Now on a different sheet ( same file ) I want a formula to look up the value I enter, and compare it to the table. Say if I enter 3, it must give back the answer TW. If I enter 2 it must give back O etc. This is completely dynamic ( only static thing is the list of numbers which is 15 ). I can't find any function(s) to effectively compare the value to the matrix and return the value next to it.

Anyway, lots of probs if you can find this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$15,C1,2)
```

Where `A1: B15` represents your 15 rows and 2 columns 
`c1` is a dynamic number you can enter to specify which row is returned, and the 2 represents the column value extracted.

This assumes that your row numbers are in column A and the text values are in column B

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a function by yourself.something like this.

```
=IF(A1=1,"G",IF(A1=2,"O",IF(A1=3,"TW","SOMETHING ELSE")))
```

Comment: Yeah - but I was looking for an IF formula to look it up by itself. Due to the fact there's over 20 matrixes. Is there any way to make the IF formula look up a range and automaticly echo back the table next to it?